# Why does the cost matrix need to be nonnegative when applying the Hungarian algorithm?

Tags: optimization, algorithms

In the "Setting" section of the Wikipedia page for [the Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), it says:

"We are given a nonnegative $n×n$ matrix, where the element in the i-th row and j-th column represents the cost of assigning the j-th job to the i-th worker. We have to find an assignment of the jobs to the workers that has minimum cost."

Why does the cost matrix have to be nonnegative?

Comment: I bet in some step of the algorithm you have to take a minimum with respect to some of those values/sums of those values and if the numbers were negative, you could keep on adding a specific cost that the solution would always be getting better.

Comment: if you get a problem with some negative entries, you add a constant to all the entries. This does not change the optimal assignment,

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks, I understand that.  However, I would like to know why it is required (if it really is) for the cost matrix to be nonnegative rather than how to modify a matrix to make it satisfy the requirement.